# Unexpected token when creating a string expression?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

I have the following code:

```
public void UpdateCardSetColumn(CARD cardColumn, bool value, string cardId)
{
    string strValue = value ? "1" : "0";

    sql = $"UPDATE Card SET {cardColumn.Text()} = {strValue}​ WHERE CardGuid = '{​cardId}​'";

    RunExecute(db2, sql);
}
```

There is an error here `'{cardId`

And it tells me

> Invalid Expression term "

Comment: Your strvalue has to be in single quotes. EDIT: Answer is not complete. If the column name point to a text field in the DB it has to be between single quotes. In case of a numeric value this is not needed.

Comment: What's the value of `cardColumn.Text()`? Also, beware of [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I would like to point out that your construction with adding text directly from some input field will be a security risk. SQL injection is very possible with this construct.

Comment: Use an ORM like the Entity Framework. Makes working with data in databases so much easier.

Comment: @PaulSinnema - agreed about strValue, but why is it getting upset about the single quote before {cardId ?

Comment: My guess is that the confusion is because of the missing single quotes on the third argument. What's the type of the column you try to update?

Comment: Problem was some unseen character in the text.  Fixed now.  Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Still be aware of the danger of SQL injection. If someone enters ";delete * from tablename';" into strValue all rows in the tablename will be erased when the program has the correct rights to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be aware that this kind of string concatenation is avoided and it is open to SQL Injection attack, you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and also to get rid of errors, something like this:

```
sql = "UPDATE Card SET cardColumn = @strValue​ WHERE CardGuid = @​cardId";
yourSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strValue​ ", cardColumn.Text);
yourSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@​cardId", ​cardId);
```

Although specifying the type directly and using the `Value` property is better than `AddWithValue`:

```
yourSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@​cardId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ​cardId;
```

Read more here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Note that `AddWithValue()` is [not recommended](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and has its caveats. `.Add().Value` should be used instead.

Comment: @41686d6564 Thanks, agree. I was working on the answer, updated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed when the line was entered again.  There must have been some non-ascii character in the text as it's working good now.